# Unity 2d method don't reach the Update method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I tried to modify my code for it to be able to move the character by using UI buttons as I am making a mobile game. Before, the code looked incredible and worked, but since I tried to add the stop when the player released the button, it no longer works. There are no errors, but the character doesn't want to jump and move. I tried using ChatGPT to solve this problem, but he ran out of ideas and cycled the same codes.
**Here is his last written code that causes a problem:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 5f;
    private bool isJumping = false;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Animator animator;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isFalling;
    private bool isRunning;

    public Button moveLeftButton;
    public Button moveRightButton;
    public Button jumpButton;

    private bool isMovingLeft = false;
    private bool isMovingRight = false;
    private bool isJumpButtonPressed = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        moveLeftButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMoveLeftButtonDown);
        moveLeftButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMoveLeftButtonUp);
        moveRightButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMoveRightButtonDown);
        moveRightButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMoveRightButtonUp);
        jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(OnJumpButtonDown);
        jumpButton.onClick.AddListener(OnJumpButtonUp);
    }

    public void OnMoveLeftButtonDown()
    {
        isMovingLeft = true;
    }

    public void OnMoveLeftButtonUp()
    {
        isMovingLeft = false;
    }

    public void OnMoveRightButtonDown()
    {
        isMovingRight = true;
    }

    public void OnMoveRightButtonUp()
    {
        isMovingRight = false;
    }

    public void OnJumpButtonDown()
    {
        isJumpButtonPressed = true;
    }

    public void OnJumpButtonUp()
    {
        isJumpButtonPressed = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isMovingLeft)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
            isRunning = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsRunning", isRunning);
        }
        else if (isMovingRight)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
            isRunning = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsRunning", isRunning);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y);
            isRunning = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsRunning", isRunning);
        }

        if (isJumpButtonPressed && !isJumping)
        {
            Jump();
        }

        isFalling = rb.velocity.y < 0f && !isJumping;
        animator.SetBool("IsFalling", isFalling);
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", isJumping);
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        isJumping = true;
        animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isJumping = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", isJumping);
        }
    }
}
```

*I debugged this code using Debug.Log and discovered that the*

```
    public void OnMoveLeftButtonDown()
    {
        isMovingLeft = true;
    }

    public void OnMoveLeftButtonUp()
    {
        isMovingLeft = false;
    }

    public void OnMoveRightButtonDown()
    {
        isMovingRight = true;
    }

    public void OnMoveRightButtonUp()
    {
        isMovingRight = false;
    }

    public void OnJumpButtonDown()
    {
        isJumpButtonPressed = true;
    }

    public void OnJumpButtonUp()
    {
        isJumpButtonPressed = false;
    }
```

*Methods are working but not used in the Update method.*

Are there any ideas to rewrite this code to work again and add a stop for a character when the player releases it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you sure the script is enabled? the script can be on a game object and disabled, it allows running of methods, but doesnt run all the updates etc.

Comment: Yes, I tested it just right now. It was enabled. Anyway, the movement worked before I tried to add movement with UI buttons.

Comment: ok, so no errors? or warnings?, what happens when you add debug statements to see what its doing?

Comment: I debugged the second box of code in this post. They were all working. But when I debugged the Update method, there was no response in the console. There are no errors or warnings, and everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

The issue you are facing is because you are registering on the same event twice in your `Start` function:

```cs
    private void Start()
    {
        //code
        moveLeftButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMoveLeftButtonDown);
        moveLeftButton.onClick.AddListener(OnMoveLeftButtonUp);
        //More code
    }
```

This will cause both methods to be triggered right as the button is pressed, causing then the reaction of always setting the `isMovingLeft` (for instance) to be false.

### Solving

For the requested behaviour, I'd recommend you to not use the `Button` class from UI due to its limitation of reading its state as its main purpose is to fire 'onClick' events, whereas you're looking for something like [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) and  [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html). To implement `EventSystem` interfaces is quite easy:

1. Be sure to have an active `GraphicsRaycaster` component
2. Be sure to have an active `EventSystem` GameObject (to create it, right-click on the Scene/Hierarchy then go to `UI -> Event System` and it shall be added properly)

*Both can also be added by creating a Canvas on the scene, so if you have one, you'll probably be set (but worth to check).*

Those interfaces shall then be implemented on an UI script of yours, this way you can manage custom UI such as joysticks

Comment: I solved this problem. I just created a separate script that uses the IPointerUpHandler and IPointerDownHandler—and referred to it in the CharacterController script in the Update method. Then I added this separate script to the Image, and now everything works perfectly. Thank you for being so helpful!

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed to solve it :)